# Jquery ajax json post to php variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, post

I am looping through a mysql table and printing an HTML "Play" link for each row.

I'm trying to avoid refreshing the page on every click of the 'Play' link so I'm placing javascript in the link's 'href':

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='playMV(\"".$rows["v_type"]."\",\"".$rows["v_id"]."\");'>Play</a>
```

The playMV() function will send necessary info to the server via jquery ajax post to get back out needed values. The php script on the server will use the values posted as values in a mysql query.

```
// javascript:

<script type="text/javascript">
    function playMV(p1, p2) {
        $.post("?opt=music", {
            var1: p1,
            var2: p2
        }, function (data) {
            //$('#result').html(p2);
        });
    }
</script>


// PHP:
$var1 = $_POST['var1'];
$var2 = $_POST['var2'];

$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE v_lang='".$var1."' AND v_id='".$var2."'");
```

My question is: I don't know how to call both 'p1' and 'p2' values and assigned into php variable. the commented line `$('#result').html(p2)` was only output the values in a div block with id='result' but don't really can get it pass to php. I've been read through some answer regarding on json stuffs but end up can't even get what I want.

Please help as I've been stuck quite long in this part.

Thanks very much!!!

```
// whole code

<script type="text/javascript">
    function playMV(p1, p2) {
        $.post("<?php echo curPageURL() ?>", {
            var1: p1,
            var2: p2
        }, function (data) {
            //$('#result').html(p2);
            //$('#result').html(data);
        });
    }
</script>


<?php
mysql_set_charset("utf8");

$var1 = $_POST['var1'];
$mvid = $_POST['var2'];

echo $var1.$var2;

//echo var_dump($_POST);

$count = 1;

if((strpos(curPageURL(),'mv')==false) || (strpos(curPageURL(),'type')==false)){
$type = ucwords("C");
$mvid = 1;
}

$mtv_data = array();
$mtvlist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$tb01." WHERE mtv_type='".$type."' ORDER BY     mtv_order ASC LIMIT 0, 10") or die(mysql_error());

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($mtvlist)){
$mtv_data[] = $rows;
}

$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$tb01." WHERE mtv_id='".$mvid."'") or die(mysql_error());
$r = mysql_fetch_array($q);
?>

<span id="result"></span>

<div align="center" class="content-layer1" style="height:600px;padding-bottom:20px;">
<div class="content-layer2">
    <div style="width:900px;text-align:left;padding:18px 18px 8px 18px;">
        <h1>MUSIC ZONE</h1>
    </div>
    <div style="width:900px;text-align:left;padding:10px;">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="55%">
            <div id='mediaspace' align='center'>
            <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif">
            </div>
            <div><?php echo $r["mtv_title"] ?><br /><?php echo $r["mtv_artist"] ?>  </div>
            </td>
            <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <div style="border:0px #000 solid;">
            <table width='100%' border='1' cellspacing='2' cellpadding='2'>
            <?php
    foreach($mtv_data as $rows){
        echo "<tr>
                <td>".$count."</td>
            <td><div>".$rows["mtv_title"]."</div><div>".$rows["mtv_artist"]."</div></td>
            <td><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='playMV(\"".$rows["mtv_type"]."\",\"".$rows["mtv_id"]."\");' id='playmv'>Play</a>
            </td>
          </tr>";
        $count += 1;
    }
            ?>
            </table>
            </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>


    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem here? in php, does `$val1` turn out to be the same as `p1` in javascript? I don't see anything wrong with your code, except 1. why are you posting to "?opt=music"? 2. have you heard of SQL injection?

Answer (score 1):

use json_decode()

```
$object = json_decode(json_string)
```

Comment: actually, jquery will automatically convert the json arguments into POST args. No need for `json_decode`.

Comment: if that was the case, then the op shouldn't have had any trouble with it. Maybe one of the values is a stringified object :S

Comment: hi, regarding from my script, how can i assign my post data into "$object = json_decode(json_string)"?

Comment: install firebug and look at the `net` tab. It should clear things up.

Comment: i installed firebug and check on the 'XHR' option, under 'Post' tab, its returned me 

Parameters:
var1 - C
var2 - 10
 
Source:
var1=C&var2=10

That is exactly the values where the function had returned, but i echo out 'var1' and 'var2' still see empty. any advice?

Comment: After the hundred times of test, i still can't get the post value pass to php variable.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` and use firebug to see what it is.

Comment: I echo "var_dump($_POST)" and returned me "array(0){ }", from firebug i can see "var1=C&var2=4".